# Drag and Drop - Save ordering to array field

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using React Beautiful Dnd for reordering items.

This is all working well, but as part of my onDragEnd I am using the following:

```js
function onDragEnd(result) {
    const newItems = [...customgearUpdate];
    const [removed] = newItems.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    newItems.splice(result.destination.index, 0, removed);
    newItems[result.destination.index].catid = result.destination.index;
    setcustomgearUpdate(newItems);
}
```

This saves the array to the order I have set the items by using drag and drop - but how do I save this ordering back to the `catid` field?

The code `newItems[result.destination.index].catid = result.destination.index;` saves the destination index to the catid field - so while it does this, it only saves it for that particular item.

How do I save the current index of these items back to every item in the array (using the catid field)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can to loop through `newItems` and set `catid` to the index of the item to put them in order:

```
function onDragEnd(result) {
    const newItems = [...customgearUpdate];
    const [removed] = newItems.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    newItems.splice(result.destination.index, 0, removed);
    newItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.catid = index;
    });
    setcustomgearUpdate(newItems);
}
```